# What is the Python equivalent of http client connections in Java?

Tags: java, python, apache, python-2.7, http

Basically I have the following classes in Java and I want the Python 2.7 equivalent library for it (if it exists):

- CloseableHttpClient
- HttpClientConnectionManager
- PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager
- RequestConfig
- HttpClientBuilder
- HttpRoutePlanner
- CredentialsProvider

The libraries can be built-in or external. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: These are class names from the ``apache-httpclient`` library. I wouldn't expect the class names or their behaviour to be identical in python. Even if you use a python library, it will likely look different.

Comment: Yes it is, but is there any python library which does similar functions as the above classes?

Comment: Python requests maybe? http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/